# Performing same action on multiple tables in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

This is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do. In brief, I create some matrices that I want to perform the same action on, like in a loop. In this example here I want to print the summary for each matrix, but I don't know how to refer to the matrices in a for loop. Any help is much appreciated:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  x <- paste0('df', i)
  assign(x, matrix(sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3))
  print(summary(eval(x)))
}
```

Returns (it is evaluating 'df3' as a string):

```
   Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character 
   Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character 
   Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character
```

How do I get it to return the following?

```
       V1             V2            V3    
 Min.   : 1.0   Min.   :3.0   Min.   : 5  
 1st Qu.: 5.0   1st Qu.:3.0   1st Qu.: 5  
 Median : 6.0   Median :4.0   Median : 7  
 Mean   : 5.6   Mean   :5.2   Mean   : 7  
 3rd Qu.: 6.0   3rd Qu.:7.0   3rd Qu.: 8  
 Max.   :10.0   Max.   :9.0   Max.   :10 

       V1          V2            V3      
 Min.   :2   Min.   :1.0   Min.   : 4.0  
 1st Qu.:4   1st Qu.:3.0   1st Qu.: 4.0  
 Median :7   Median :3.0   Median : 6.0  
 Mean   :6   Mean   :3.4   Mean   : 6.6  
 3rd Qu.:8   3rd Qu.:4.0   3rd Qu.: 9.0  
 Max.   :9   Max.   :6.0   Max.   :10.0  

       V1            V2             V3     
 Min.   :1.0   Min.   : 5.0   Min.   :1.0  
 1st Qu.:2.0   1st Qu.: 6.0   1st Qu.:2.0  
 Median :6.0   Median : 6.0   Median :3.0  
 Mean   :5.2   Mean   : 6.8   Mean   :2.4  
 3rd Qu.:8.0   3rd Qu.: 7.0   3rd Qu.:3.0  
 Max.   :9.0   Max.   :10.0   Max.   :3.0
```

Comment: You should save your objects into a `list` instead of using `assign`...it's unnecessary and makes things more complicated than they need to be. Also be cautious about terminology: your code shows matrices, and you say "data tables", so what kind of object are you really interested in?

Comment: @Thomas you're right, edited to reflect your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don’t use distinct variables and `paste` their names – put your objects into a list:

```
x = Map(function (i) matrix(sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3), 1 : 3)
```

Then performing a common operation on them is trivial as well:

```
Map(summary, x)
```

[`Map`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) maps a function onto a list. It operates similar to the [`lapply` and `mapply` family of functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

Comment: Wouldn't `lapply` be more directly appropriate in this case? `Map` is just a wrapper around `mapply`, which is a multivariate version of `(l/s)apply`.

Comment: @thelatemail I’ve completely switched to `Map` (although I’ve aliased it to `map`) a as a uniform alternative. `map` is the established name of this operation in virtually every functional language except R. There’s really no need for either `lapply` or `mapply` to exist. I also prefer the order of arguments in `Map` compared to `lapply`, and I especially dislike that the latter has a different argument order from `mapply`.

Comment: Fair enough. I admittedly have a very R-centric view of programming. I do like being able to do things like `lapply(x, "[", 1, )` to get the first row of each matrix in a list, which requires something like `Map(function(y) y[1,], x)` alternatively.

Comment: @thelatemail ``Map(`[`, x, 1)`` works as well. More generally, I make partial function application explicit though: ``Map(lp(`[`, 1), x)`` in your case. `lp` (and `p`) is a simple function to partially apply a function: https://github.com/klmr/rcane/blob/master/functional.R#L81 – in fact, I would write this particular example as `map(item(1), x)`.

Comment: Yep, but `lapply(x, "[", 1, )` succeeds where `Map("[", x, 1, )` fails - note the missing argument in both instances. You are clearly across the issues and know what you doing though - thanks for the link.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, interesting case. You can work around this via ``Map(p(`[`, 1, quote(expr=)), x)``. But now I’m just arguing for argument’s sake: I don’t advocate this as being clear code. ;-) So you win this round. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `eval(as.name("df3"))` or `get("df3")`

Comment: The above mentioned method won't work (at least not as straight forward) if what you're trying to access is one of the variables of a list or the columns of a dataframe. I was struggling to use the value stored in one of a list's variables, and solved it by something of the form: `L<-list(val.A=1,val.B=2);for (i in c("A","B") as.numeric(L[paste("val.",i,sep="")])*2`. Hope it helps someone else!